# How to unset an environment variable using php?

Tags: php, bash, environment-variables, hhvm

I know I can set an environment variable using

```
putenv("ENV_FOO=SOMETHING");
```

and get the value via:

```
getenv("ENV_FOO");
```

If the variable isn't set, `getenv("ENV_FOO")` will return `false`.

I have a feature set that *may* be set via an environment variable, and I wanted to unit test the behavior when the variable is set or not set.

Yet once export the variable on my dev machine in bash via

```
export ENV_FOO=something`
```

it breaks my unit test, as I cannot unset the environment variable using php for the scope of the test.

I tried `putenv("ENV_FOO=");` yet this will return in an empty string `""`, not in an unset environment variable for the current shell session.

Is there a way to unset an environment variable for the current shell session, or do I have to change the way I test for the existence of the variable?

Answer (score 32):

Try this from the [`putenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) docpage comments

```
<?php
putenv('MYVAR='); // set MYVAR to an empty value.  It is in the environment
putenv('MYVAR'); // unset MYVAR.  It is removed from the environment
?>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Then I realized again that I am using hhvm which has a bug of this not working: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2533

Comment: sorry to hear this :( you can try `shell_exec("unset FOO");` if you haven't set the env. variable from withing php itself, might work

Comment: I attempted this approach in a docker container on PHP 7.0 with no luck, the env var value was still set once the container was built.